# How is a integer created as a character code constant?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

I am building some test cases for [integer/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=integer/1) using SWI-Prolog.

ISO/IEC 13211-1 gives a BNF definition for `integer` and one of the alternatives for integer is for a `character code constant`.

I am able to create and test examples of all the other alternatives using `integer/1` but for `character code constant` I cannot create a valid example. (see below)

How is an integer as a `character code constant` created that will return true using [integer/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=integer/1)?

---

Answer

Thanks to @false.

```
integer(0'0).
true.

integer(0'9).
true.

integer(0'a).
true.

integer(0'\n).
true.
```

---

Usefulness

```
X is 0'\n.
X = 10.

X is 0b010101.
X = 21.

X is 0xFFF1.
X = 65521.

X is 0o7423.
X = 3859.
```

and thanks to [j4n bur53](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.prolog/8hYtN-mZox4) via link from @false

with SWI-Prolog other radix can be used besides 2,8, or 16.

```
X is 5'1234012340.
X = 3032220.

X is 32'123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU.
X = 47525417447024678661670292427038339608998846.
```

---

What I tried

```
integer("0").
false.

integer('0').
false.

integer(`0`).
false.

integer("1").
false.

integer('1').
false.

integer(`1`).
false.
```

---

ISO

INTERNATIONAL STANDARD  ISO/IEC 13211-1 First edition 1995-06-01
    Information technology - Programming languages - Prolog
    Part 1: General Core

INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995
    TECHNICAL CORRIGENDUM 1
    Published 2007-11-15

INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995
    TECHNICAL CORRIGENDUM 2
    Published 2012-02-15

BNF for `integer`

```
integer token (* 6.4.4 *) =  
    integer constant (* 6.4.4 *)
  | character code constant (* 6.4.4 *)
  | binary constant (* 6.4.4 *)
  | octal constant (* 6.4.4 *)
  | hexadecimal constant (* 6.4.4 *) ;
```

BNF for `character code constant`

```
character code constant (* 6.4.4 *) =  
  "0" , single quote char (* 6.5.5 *), single quoted character (* 6.4.2.1 *)
```

I suspect the BNF is wrong in ISO/IEC 13211-1 but checking the CORRIGENDUM shows no corrections.

---

Integer test cases

```
% <integer constant> examples

number(1). 
% true.

number(0).
% true.

number(01).
% true.

number(12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890).
% true.

% <character code constant> examples

% ???

% <binary constant> examples

number(0b0).  
% true.

number(0b10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010). 
% true.

integer(0b2).
% ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal number
% ERROR: integer
% ERROR: ** here **
% ERROR: (0b2) .

% <octal constant> examples

integer(0o7). 
% true.

integer(0o1234567012345670123456701234567012345670123456701234567). 
% true.

integer(0o8).
% ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal number
% ERROR: integer
% ERROR: ** here **
% ERROR: (0o8) . 

% <hexadecimal constant>

integer(0x0). 
% true.

integer(0xF). 
% true.

integer(0xf). 
% true.

integer(0x123456789ABCDEF012345670123456789ABCDEF012345670123456789ABCDEF). 
% true.

integer(0xG).
% ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal number
% ERROR: integer
% ERROR: ** here **
% ERROR: (0xG) .
```

Comment: The character code constant for zero is `0'0`. Not sure what you do not understand here.

Comment: Thanks. Then single `'` is throwing me off.

Comment: Post the answer and I will give you the votes.

Comment: With `integer(0'a).` it now makes more sense.

Comment: Will do, but there is a little bit more to note :-) In particular, from [#212](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#212) onward.

Comment: [Related](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.prolog/8hYtN-mZox4).

Comment: Related: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/tests/prolog/NOTES.md

Comment: @PauloMoura: Which of your test cases contain`0'`?

Comment: @false I don't know Logtalk, but there are a few files with this [line](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/a1cb0eb2a34b6265f580420730f783546f97f98d/coding/tests/source.lgt#L236)  <- The link in the comment is hard to see.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Thanks for the reference! Actually the rule starting with `numbers :- ...` is invalid Prolog syntax, because `... C2 is 0'', ...` is invalid. This has to be either `... C2 is 0''', ...` or `... C2 is 0'\', ...`

Comment: @GuyCoder The specific file you linked, `source.lgt`, is there *just* for testing syntax coloring support. Nothing to do with unit tests.

Comment: @false `0''` is supported syntax in B-Prolog, CxProlog, Ciao, GNU Prolog, ECLiPSe, JIProlog, Qu-Prolog, SWI-Prolog, XSB, YAP. Lean Prolog doesn't support the `0'` notation. SICStus Prolog requires `0'''`.

Comment: @false Given that we're talking about number syntax, they are in the obvious place: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/tests/prolog/syntax/numbers We could use a few more tests there, however. Contributions welcome.

Comment: @PauloMoura: The question is about standard-conforming behavior. See [#114](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#114) ... #117: B and GNU reject`0''` - you must have a very old version of those.

Comment: @PauloMoura: [See this table](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment) for further test cases.

Comment: @false Latest stable versions of both. B-Prolog 8.1 and GNU Prolog 1.4.4. GNU Prolog only rejects `0''` when the `strict_iso` flag is on.

Comment: @PauloMoura: What is of relevance is default behavior, not some special mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by false in a comment.
Reposting here so that others can see an answer exist.

```
integer(0'0).
true.

integer(0'9).
true.

integer(0'a).
true.

integer(0'\n).
true.
```